# show 10 most recent custom post types excluding the one(s) from specific custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms, exclude

After spending most of the day looking for solutions and trying them out, I decided to explain my problem here.

I am aware that this subject has been covered and as you will see I am using code that has been suggested here and over at ottopress, but I still cannot figure it out.

I have a custom post type called 'review' (non-hierarchical)
I have a custom taxonomy called 'reviewcats' (hierarchical)
I have a whole bunch of terms under the taxonomy of which 3 are main and the rest children:

- featured
- applications (containing children)
- games (containing children)

On my homepage template I am first showing the latest review (custom post type) that has the term 'featured' from the 'reviewcats' taxonomy. That review also contains the terms 'applications' and a child thereof.

Under the Feature I would like to show the 10 most recent reviews (custom post type), **but** not the one from above, the one with the term 'featured'

I have been trying with the code below (and many variations of it), but cannot get it right. Can anyone shed light on this dark matter for me please? Much appreciated!

```
$recentapps_query['tax_query'] = array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'post_type' => 'review',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => 10,
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'reviewcats',
                    'terms' => array('featured'),
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                ),
            );
            query_posts($recentapps_query);
```

if needed, the sandbox site is http://senl.in/jOaalP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your tax query is a little jumbled. The first nested array should actually be at the 'root' of your `query_posts()` argument, with `tax_query` as a key among them;

```
array(
    'post_type' => 'review',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'reviewcats',
            'terms' => array( 'featured' ),
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        )
    )
);
```

**However**, forgive me if I'm mistaken, but I think your query could be a lot simpler - simply exclude the 'featured' review you've just grabbed;

```
query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'review',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ) // $post *should* be the featured review, since it was the last post queried/worked on 
) );
```

Comment: just beat me to it, Just a Note: and since its not the main query you should use WP_query or get_posts and not query_posts.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic thanks for your input, very possible that things are getting jumbled on my end, been staring at the code and changing it around a bit too often today I think... Anyways both your samples don't work. I started with your 2nd suggestion as it made sense, but that didn't work at all: errors. Then I tried the first one and it also gives me errors. Perhaps it is better to see the whole picture? I therefore have pasted part of my homepage.php file here: http://senlin.pastebin.ca/2076198 @Bainternet, tried it too with your suggestion, but didn't seem to make any difference

Comment: no other input on this? guess I will have to start over from scratch to figure it out... will post a working solution once i have accomplished it.

Comment: I'm having a go at your pastebin now ;)

Comment: Okay, check it out - http://senlin.pastebin.ca/2076755 - You had quite a few HTML nesting errors, and the troublemaker was that you were resetting the query after the featured app, thus overwriting the `$post` used for excluding from recent apps.

Comment: terrific @TheDeadMedic! You nailed it and I learned a lot! there was one typo on line 68 so the final version is http://senlin.pastebin.ca/2077121 Thanks so much for solving this for me!